# tfs extension with menu control childs - childs not showing

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to create extension which allow me to open a work item context menu and see new control and when I hover on the control a sub menu will open. just like the way 'Move to iteration' and 'Templates' works.

this is the contributions section of my vss-extension.json:

```
"contributions": [
        {
            "id": "releaseMenuAction",
            "type": "ms.vss-web.action",
            "description": "test",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-work-web.backlog-item-menu",
                "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-context-menu"
                ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "releaseMenuAction",
                "text": "Assign to release",
                "title": "Assign to release",
                "icon": "img/delivery_small.png",
                "uri": "index.html"
            }
        }
    ]
```

and this is the html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="sdk/VSS.SDK.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    VSS.init({ usePlatformScripts: true, usePlatformStyles: true, explicitNotifyLoaded: true });

    // Use an IIFE to create an object that satisfies the IContributedMenuSource contract
    var menuContributionHandler = (function () {
        "use strict";
        return {
            getMenuItems: function (actionContext) {
                var subMenus = [
                    {
                        text: "one",
                        action: function (actionContext) {
                            alert("one");
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: "two",
                        action: function (actionContext) {
                            alert("two");
                        }
                    }
                ];

                return [
                    {
                        text: "Assign to release",
                        group: "actions",
                        icon: "img/delivery_small.png",
                        childItems: subMenus
                    }
                ];
            }
        };
    }());

    // Associate the menuContributionHandler object with the "releaseMenuAction" menu contribution from the manifest.
    VSS.register("releaseMenuAction", menuContributionHandler);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

The result I'm getting is only to see the 'Assign to release' control in the menu but without his childs.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you mean you  need the the  [Menubar control](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/controls/menubar) feature?

Comment: No. I mean work item menu. from the backlog screen every work item has this 3 dots button which opens a menu or from the work item itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PatrickLu-MSFT Thanks for the reply.

I managed to solved the problem. I was missing a line in the code:

VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();

this line "tells" the tfs that the extension loaded succesfully.